# Magnetic force on a current carrying wire looped into a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

How would you find the lorentz force on a current-carrying wire that is looped into a solenoid?

As a followup question:

How could one use the amount of force calculated to determine whether a wire will be able to hold to those forces.

Comment: What do you mean by looped in a solenoid?

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq I was just referring to when you coil up a wire into a solenoid.

Comment: Have you searched for 'magnetic force'?

Answer (score 0):

in an ideal solenoid the magnetic field is constant and the equation of the magnetic field is given as $\vec{B}=\mu_{0} n I_{1}$.

The force on the loop wire is given as
$\vec{F}=I_{2} \oint \vec{d} l \times \vec{B}$ ,since $B$ is constant it'll come out of the integral, hence

$\vec{F}=I_{2}(\oint \overrightarrow{d l}) \times \vec{B}$

But $\oint \overrightarrow{d l}=0$ since the total displacement is zero,

$\Rightarrow \vec{F}=0$.

So the   total force on the wire is zero however the wire will  have tension in it due to the stretch on the wire.

Comment: What do you mean by tension? Would adding current cause the wire to stretch?

Comment: Yes it can lead to stretch or shrink due to magnetic force on the charges moving inside the wire. See Lorentz Force.

Comment: How could I calculate this tension in order to determine the resulting structural integrity of the wire in the solenoid?

Comment: There is some discssion of the forces on solenoiud magnets in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_electromagnet.